# How to copy a layer's mask photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, mask

In photoshop, I have a layer with a mask.

I want to duplicate this mask to then apply it to another layer.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The easiest way to duplicate a layer mask is by holding the <kbd>Alt</kbd> *(win)* or <kbd>Option</kbd> *(mac)* key while dragging the layer mask thumbnail to another layer in the layer panel.

Comment: Is this for both Mac & Windows OS?

Comment: @AdrienBe yes, sorry usually I put both. Updated to specify

Comment: To clarify: The modifier key (Alt / Option) needs to be held before the dragging operation is started.

Answer (score 4):

Here are the steps:

1. Deselect everything.
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + `click` (<kbd>Cmd</kbd> +`click`for mac) the mask you want to copy (be sure to click the mask thumbnail, not the layer name)
3. Click on another layer (the one that you want to apply the mask you just selected)
4. Finally click Add vector mask button (see pic below)

[image: Add vector mask button]

This is also explained on http://planetphotoshop.com/creating-and-duplicating-a-layer-mask.html

Answer (score 2):

I discovered another way to duplicate a mask:

1. Click on the mask thumbnail you want to duplicate;
2. Click on the 'Load selection' button in the 'Properties' panel (or go to 'Select → Load Selection');
3. In the 'Adjustments' panel, click a 'New Layer Type' button, or go to 'Layer → New Adjustment/Fill Layer'. The trick here is to remember to **have the selection loaded first**, otherwise you end up with a blank mask.

Comment: *VERY* useful when you don't have an Alt/Option key. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Mask is already created on the existing layer.

1) Create a new layer

2) Right-click mask on Layers tab and select 'Add Mask To Selection'

3) Go back to the new layer